# How to fix "Error: spawn ENAMETOOLONG" (probably cause by jq) in javascript?

Tags: javascript, node.js, jq

*I'm on windows 10, and I work with node.js, and I work with node-jq@1.10.0 (the lastest version at this moment)*

I want to retrieve some information from a JSON with jq.
So I use jq.run function with 'json' as option parameter.
But it throw me an error, I know my queries are good, and all my code work without the line which start with "*let AllKOMoves = ...*".

My JSON are well formatted and I try this program in JMES Path and it's work well, so there no problem with JSON. I did some researches and some people said that my OS cannot support a too long request. I want to precise that on of my JSON weighs 6Mo.

I did some researches on internet and some of them talk about "**Not specifying a .catch(…)**" on this website: [here](https://mrcoles.com/javascript-promises-and-errors/) and this one talk about the **too long query**: [here](https://github.com/Turbo87/webpack-notifier/issues/45)

Here's my code I put the `const jq = require('node-jq');` out of the async function.

```
(async ()=>{
    let name = "abomasnow"; 
    const fileContent = fs.readFileSync(`./Pokemon with move CSV/Queries/nonStatusMove/${name}nonStatusMove.csv`);
    let pokemonSubject = JSON.parse(await jq.run(`. | map(select(.name == "${name}"))[0]`, './nameBSTypeAbilityWeight.json'));
    var allMoves = moveToJSON(fileContent);
    let AllKOMoves = await jq.run(`. | map(select(.Moves | map(select(.Max == 100)) | length > 1)) | map({Nature: .Nature, EV: .EV, Moves: [.Moves | map(select(.Max == 100))[] | .Move], MovesCount: .Moves | length})`,getAllInflictedDamage(pokemonSubject, allMoves, pokemonJSON[0]),{ input: 'json' })
    console.log(AllKOMoves);
    })();
```

Here's a sample of the JSON generate by this portion of code `getAllInflictedDamage(pokemonSubject, allMoves, pokemonJSON[0])`:

```
[  
   {  
      "Opponent":"abomasnow",
      "Move":"wood-hammer",
      "Min":16.15,
      "Max":19.25,
      "Crit":28.88
   },
   {  
      "Opponent":"abomasnow",
      "Move":"round",
      "Min":15.84,
      "Max":18.94,
      "Crit":28.26
   }
]
```

Here's is a sample of the JSON contains in the variable `allMoves`:

```
[  
   {  
      "name":"bulldoze",
      "accuracy":"100",
      "category":"physical",
      "power":"60",
      "priority":"0",
      "target":"all-other-pokemon",
      "type":"ground"
   },
   {  
      "name":"frost-breath",
      "accuracy":"90",
      "category":"special",
      "power":"60",
      "priority":"0",
      "target":"selected-pokemon",
      "type":"ice"
   }
]
```

I expected the content of my JSON, but it throw this error message:

```
(node:21792) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: spawn ENAMETOOLONG
    at ChildProcess.spawn (internal/child_process.js:366:11)
    at Object.spawn (child_process.js:538:9)
    at C:\Users\adela\node_modules\node-jq\lib\exec.js:24:43
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at exec (C:\Users\adela\node_modules\node-jq\lib\exec.js:20:10)
    at C:\Users\adela\node_modules\node-jq\lib\jq.js:24:24
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at Object.run (C:\Users\adela\node_modules\node-jq\lib\jq.js:19:10)
    at C:\Users\adela\node_code\calcDamage1forAll.js:757:28
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)
(node:21792) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 2)
(node:21792) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

Normally my code should retrieve information like this:

```
[  
   {  
      "Nature":"brave",
      "EV":[  
         4,
         0,
         0,
         0,
         252,
         252
      ],
      "Moves":[  
         "focus-punch",
         "natural-gift-fire90",
         "natural-gift-fire100",
         "natural-gift-fire80"
      ],
      "MovesCount":4
   },
   {  
      "Nature":"brave",
      "EV":[  
         0,
         252,
         252,
         4,
         0,
         0
      ],
      "Moves":[  
         "natural-gift-fire90",
         "natural-gift-fire100",
         "natural-gift-fire80"
      ],
      "MovesCount":3
   }
]
```

EDIT: If I only do this:

```js
let AllKOMoves = await jq.run(`.`,getAllInflictedDamage(pokemonSubject, allMoves, pokemonJSON[0]),{ input: 'json' })
```

it also give me the same error !

EDIT2: If I do this:

```js
let AllKOMoves = await jq.run(`.`,{"foo":"bar"},{ input: 'json' })
```

it work perfectly ! With some researches I think it's just about the size of json because my json size ~12Mo, I try with a 300 Ko json it doesn't work too so I think just my json are too big.

**My question now is to know if it exists other solution that create a temporary files like it proposed in the first answer...**

Comment: It's jq language, it's not jquery, because I don't use jquery in my code, it's only jq

Comment: If you want help on the jq side, you'll have to provide a sample of the JSON.

Comment: @peak I tried to put all of my JSON sample, include what I would had if I used JMES Path instead of jq(the past result). Now I know jq is better so that's why I try to work with jq.

Comment: What is the value of `${name}`?  There are two jq commands.  Have you tried arranging things so you can find out whether the first one succeeds?

Comment: ${name} define at the first line with `let name = "abomasnow"; ` and I don't think that the first jq command break because I run it very well if I comment the line which start with *"let allMoves ="*

Comment: Are you able to reproduce the issue with the sample JSON you gave? Because I was not able to reproduce

Comment: I can't really help out with missing information. Could you provide a reproducable demo with node-jq running and throwing the error? Use glitch.me

Comment: Actually I try to trigger the error on snippet or on my node just with the json in the example and I get other error I don't even know why, when I fix this I will edit my post...

Comment: The only way to trigger this error is to get a big json file

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**EDIT:**

This has now been re-examined and addressed in **node-jq 1.10.0** ([pull #191](https://github.com/sanack/node-jq/pull/194)) thanks to this question, so making sure the version of node-jq is up to date in your project's dependencies should prevent this error.

**Background for node-jq pre-1.10.0 (or people looking into ENAMETOOLARGE problems)**

The trouble with an `input:` besides 'file' is that it [gets translated by node-jq versions before 1.10.0](https://github.com/sanack/node-jq/blob/059fb1e5d427d0940b2aafa12c9fc1a7accacf49/src/options.js#L30) into a command line like `jq --null-input '[json] | [filter]'` so your JSON and filter combined must be smaller than your OS's largest acceptable single argument and/or total arguments limit, on windows this may be as small as 8192 bytes. (Most UNIX-clones should fail with [an E2BIG error instead](https://github.com/sanack/node-jq/issues/51) around for arguments around 128-256k.)

To pass a large amount of data to jq through earlier versions of node-jq without it going directly through a command line argument you would need to write to a temp file with a name ending in .json to pass your JSON using `{input:file}` if it is sizeable.

While in theory, you could provide an array of `[]` for files, making jq wait for data over stdin, `node-jq` wrapped the subprocess, so it would be ugly to get a handle on its stdin. Censequently it needed to be fixed or one would need to write an alternate wrapper to pass the data to jq over stdin, like:

```
child_process.spawn... 
process.stdin.write('myJsonAsAstring')
process.stdin.end()
```

Further discussion is available in the original [node-jq issue](https://github.com/sanack/node-jq/issues/51).

Comment: So in fact I need to, create temporary file or use many subquery instead of a big one or use jq with stdin.write... Okay..., but I have a question, where I'm supposed to put the your code: `process.stdin.write('myJsonAsAstring') 
process.stdin.end()`in my code ?

Comment: @bosskay972 if you decide to replace node-jq with your own wrapper it would need similar contents to node-jq/src/exec.js->exec(command, args, [and now data!]) where the data could be sent via write() and end() anywhere between the spawn() and the end of the promise function (lines 18-31 of the current node-jq/src/exec.js). I've restarted the discussion in the closed node-jq issue with a few comments, so maybe a better answer for using node-jq will come out of that..

Comment: Okay... So, if I sum up well: in the case I don't replace node-jq by my own wrapper, I just can't use my query(in the question post) because of my OS, and if I want to use it I need to use my own wrapper. In fact, I think I can't handle wrapper so I think I could use multiple subqueries. Or multiple subqueries in other language as JMESPath.

Comment: And I'm sorry about that but, in fact I can't even understand this portion of code `jq --null-input '$json|$filter'` Because I don't know what language it is :/...

Comment: @bosskay972 I added a comment that your summary looks correct, but I just deleted it since it looks like node-jq is being fixed: https://github.com/sanack/node-jq/pull/194

Comment: @bosskay972 please try node-jq 1.10.0 to test their stdin changes work for you on Windows.

Comment: I update my version but it give me the same error :/ `...
(node:33644) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 2)
(node:33644) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.`

Comment: it's not my entire error, I just put the end because the begining of the error seem be the same

Comment: I think you should update the question with the newer stack and test if reducing the filter to '.' also gives a ENAMETOOLONG.

Comment: Oh woow it give me the same error ! :O ! So it's not event about the query ? So it's about the input ?

Comment: The new version puts the input over stdin, so it doesnt seem consistent that the 1st call could succeed and the 2nd call to jq.run is the problem, it still fails with a simple filter and with ENAMETOOLONG since it now has shorter arguments than the 1st call. You could install node-jq with dev dependencies and `npm run test` (however that looks in windows) to make sure the new test exists and passes.

Comment: How should I use `npm run test` ? Should I use it before run my code or there is a syntaxic way to use this command on my script directly (I work with JS btw). I tried this:  `npm run myjsfile` it give me an error: `npm ERR! missing script: calcDamage1forAll

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\adela\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2019-07-31T07_54_16_457Z-debug.log`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/197272/discussion-between-bosskay972-and-lossleader).

Comment: There some probable clue in the chat, and I add some test in the main post

Comment: It finally working ! I update npm on the right folder ! If there is someon ein the same case as me, please try to update your version of node-jq in the folder of your script !